# Decrypt 3 rail encryption

Tags: python

In class we are learning about encryption. I have to write an encrypt/decrypt program. While i found the encrypt fairly easy, the decrypt is really confusing me. I cant wrap my head around how i am supposed to split the rails apart as there are many cases where they will be different lengths. This was easy to account for with 2 rails because the message length only have 2 variations. I am trying to modify my code for 2 rail decryption but it just isnt working. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my encrypt if you are curious.

```
def threeRailEncrypt(plaintext):
    ciphertext=""
    rail1=""
    rail2=""
    rail3=""

    for i in range(len(plaintext)):
        if i%3 == 0:
            rail1=rail1+plaintext[i]
        elif i%3 == 1:
            rail2=rail2+plaintext[i]
        else:
            rail3=rail3+plaintext[i]

    ciphertext=rail1+rail2+rail3

    return(ciphertext)
```

Here is what i have so far- (doesnt work yet)

```
def threeRailDecrypt(msg):
    if len(msg)%3==0:
        third=len(msg)//3
        rail1=msg[:third]
        rail2=msg[third:third*2]
        rail3=msg[third:]
        dm=""
        for i in range(third):
            dm=dm+rail1[i]
            dm=dm+rail2[i]
            dm=dm+rail3[i]
    return(dm)]
```

This doesnt work either!

```
def threeRailDecrypt(msg):
    railLen=len(msg)//3
    dm=""
    for col in range(railLen):
        for rail in range(3):
            nextLetter=(col+rail*railLen)
            dm=dm+msg[nextLetter]
    return(dm)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three Rail Decrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148729/three-rail-decrypt)

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to reverse what you do in the encryption, so in the encryption you scramble the text by splitting them up with modulo 3.
The simplest way to get the plaintext back again is to simply run the encryption method two times on the encrypted string and it will be back to plain text.

```
def threeRailDecrypt(crypt):
    for i in range(len(crypt)-2):
        crypt = threeRailEncrypt(crypt)
    return(crypt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spydon has explained what to do. I am just a giving an implementation.
Have a look at this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def threeRailDecrypt(encrypted):
    remainder = len(encrypted) % 3
    rail_lengths = [len(encrypted) / 3] * 3

    if remainder > 1: rail_lengths[1] += 1
    if remainder > 0: rail_lengths[0] += 1

    rails = [encrypted[sum(rail_lengths[:i]) : sum(rail_lengths[:i+1])] for i in range(3)]
    return ''.join(''.join(t) for t in izip_longest(*rails, fillvalue=''))
```

First, you need to know what are the sizes of your *rail* s. As there are only 3 rails (can be generalized to *n*), if the `plaintext` length was multiple of 3, all the rails are of same size. If it is not, first one goes to rail1, second one goes to rail2 (done by two `if` checks avobe). Now you  have lengths of the rails. So just get the substring of different lengths. For example if you have lengths of the rails as 4,3,3 then you have different rails as:

```
rail1 = encrypted[0:4]
rail2 = encrypted[4:7]
rail3 = encrypted[7:10]
```

This is done by the line before the last which may seem cryptic. Now it is simple; Just collect one character from each rail and join. The last line does the trick. See what [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) do.

example:

```
>>> encrypted = threeRailEncrypt("Just a naive example")
>>> decrypted = threeRailDecrypt(encrypted)
'Just a naive example' # output of decrypted
```

Comment: i dont think i understand what you are trying to say