# Three Rail Decrypt

Tags: python

Im having a ton of trouble trying to figure out how to get my decrypt function to work. It works in ideal cases where the msg is divisible by 3, but after that i am totally lost. I have a vague idea of what i have to do because i was able to get this to work with two rails, but there are more possibilities with three rails. Im quite lost :( Also all those print statements are just to try and help me figure out what is going on within my program.

```
import sys

def main():
    plaintext="abcdefgh"
    print(threeRailEncrypt(plaintext))
    print(threeRailDecrypt(threeRailEncrypt(plaintext)))


def threeRailEncrypt(plaintext):
    ciphertext=""
    rail1=""
    rail2=""
    rail3=""

    for i in range(len(plaintext)):
        if i%3 == 0:
            rail1=rail1+plaintext[i]
        elif i%3 == 1:
            rail2=rail2+plaintext[i]
        else:
            rail3=rail3+plaintext[i]

    ciphertext=rail1+rail2+rail3

    return(ciphertext)

def threeRailDecrypt(msg):
    if len(msg)%3==0:
        third=len(msg)//3
        print(third)
        rail1=msg[:third]
        rail2=msg[third:third*2]
        rail3=msg[third*2:]
        print(rail1,rail2,rail3)
        dm=""
        for i in range(third):
            dm=dm+rail1[i]
            dm=dm+rail2[i]
            dm=dm+rail3[i]
    else:
        third=(len(msg)//3)+1
        print(third)
        rail1=msg[:third]
        rail2=msg[third:third*2]
        rail3=msg[third*2:]
        print(rail1,rail2,rail3)
        dm=""
        for i in range(third):
            dm=dm+rail1[i]
            print(dm)
            dm=dm+rail2[i]
            print(dm)
            dm=dm+rail3[i]
            print(dm)
            if  len(rail2)>len(rail3):
                dm=dm+rail2[-1]
        return(dm)
main()
```

Progress-

```
def threeRailDecrypt(cypher, rails = 3):
    length = len (cypher)
    for i in range(rails):
        lens=(length//rails)
        if length % rails > i:
            lens=lens+1
        print(lens)
```

Comment: You've asked this question three times now, maintain your question and look at the new answers coming in instead of just opening a new question every day.

Comment: posts stop getting traffic after like 10 minutes.

Comment: That means you are not asking a good question. It is long and basically says "Please debug my code for me, I'm tired".

Answer (score 1):

**New**:

You just have to split up the strings again as you did in your encryption function and then iterate over them to put each character back at it's real place.

```
def decrypt(crypt):
    rails = []
    result = ""
    rails.append(crypt[:(len(crypt)+2)/3])
    rails.append(crypt[(len(crypt)+2)/3:-(len(crypt)-2)/3])
    rails.append(crypt[-(len(crypt)/3):])
    for x in range(len(crypt)):
        result += rails[x%3][:1]
        rails[x%3] = rails[x%3][1:]
    return(result)
```

I think Hyperboreus second solution is cooler though!

**OLD**(Interesting thought connected to the comments, didn't work as expected for longer strings though):

You will just have to reverse what you do in the encryption, so in the encryption you scramble the text by splitting them up with modulo 3. The simplest way to get the plaintext back again is to simply run the encryption method the length of the string minus two times on the encrypted string and it will be back to plain text.

```
def threeRailDecrypt(crypt):
    for i in range(len(crypt)-2):
        crypt = threeRailEncrypt(crypt)
    return(crypt)
```

Hyperboreus solution is the proper one, but this is a bit simpler to understand I reckon.

Example with the string test:

> test - untouched
>
> ttes - first iteration (encryption)
>
> tste - second iteration
>
> test - third iteration

Comment: ^ why does that work?

Comment: Because is "scrambles" the characters back to their original positions. See the added example in answer.

Comment: i dont think that is how i am intended to do it thanks though

Comment: I think most teachers would accept a solution like that, if it's not stated otherwise in the assignment.

Comment: @spydon Am I doing something wrong or how can you explain that `enc(enc(enc('abcde')))` yields `acebd`?

Comment: I think the number of iterations depends on the length of the text.

Comment: Sorry, only tested it with test.
Now it should work for a string with arbitrary length.

Comment: +1 from me. A lot neater, although brutally expensive (which shouldn't matter for an assignment).

Comment: wouldnt it be "academic dishonesty" if i use this method? it seems hard not to use others' ideas in this subject

Comment: As far as I remember, academic life is all about dishonesty... And it is not dishonest unless you get caught.

Comment: also i just tried this and it gave me the same string i put in

Comment: As long as you understand the concept of the solution you've learned the method, which most likely is the point of the assignment.

Comment: lol thats terrible haha bad hyperboreus bad ;)

Comment: Take also a look at my other answer. It is a lot more explicit.

Comment: @sydon your solution is just spitting out what i put in?

Comment: yea it doesnt work for certain lengths

Comment: No, it decrypts a string encrypted with threeRailEncrypt, or what do you mean? Try threeRailDecrypt(threeRailEncrypt("abcdefghijklmnop"))

Comment: Which length does it not work for?

Comment: (plaintext - abcdefghijklmno)
(encrypt - adgjmbehkncfilo)
(decrypt - ajenidmhclgbkfo)

Comment: You're right, fixed it accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

I will add a second answer with a completely different approach and more explicit code:

```
def dec2 (cypher):
    length = len (cypher)
    if length < 4: return cypher
    third = length // 3 + (1 if length % 3 else 0)
    cypher = list (cypher)
    if length % 3 == 1: cypher.insert (third * 2 - 1, '')
    return ''.join (''.join (cypher [i::third] ) for i in range (third) )
```

Or just shock your teacher:

```
enc = lambda p:''.join(p[_::3]for _ in range(3))
dec = lambda c:c if len(c)<4 else(lambda *a:(lambda c,t:
''.join(''.join(c[i::t])for i in range(t)))((lambda c,t,
l:c[:t*2-1]+(['']if l%3==1 else[])+c[t*2-1:])(*a),a [2])
)(*(lambda c:(list(c),len(c),len(c)//3+(1 if len(c)%3
else 0)))(c))
```

Comment: haha, more like get kicked out of school, this stinks this is so far beyond what we learned in class :(

Comment: Actually both code snippets are exactely the same...

Comment: you are a magician, i meant this problem is beyond what we learned in class

Comment: Don't say that. I am a learner, too. The second snippet is just "code golf" and of no use at all. I would have been happy, if I had learnt at school what you are learning now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You just need to figure out how long the different rails are:

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zip

def enc (plain, rails = 3):
    return ''.join (plain [i::rails] for i in range (rails) )

def dec (cypher, rails = 3):
    length = len (cypher)
    lens = [length // rails + (1 if length % rails > i else 0) for i in range (rails) ]
    paths = [cypher [sum (lens [:i] ):sum (lens [:i + 1] ) ] for i in range (rails) ]
    return ''.join (''.join (x for x in x if x) for x in zip (*paths) )

plain = 'abcdefghijk'
for i in range (10):
    a = plain [:i]
    b = enc (a)
    c = dec (b)
    print (a, b, c)
```

Should work for arbitrary (>0) number of rails used.

---

EDIT: Without zip_longest:

```
def enc (plain, rails = 3):
    return ''.join (plain [i::rails] for i in range (rails) )

def dec (cypher, rails = 3):
    length = len (cypher)
    lens = [length // rails + (1 if length % rails > i else 0) for i in range (rails) ]
    paths = [cypher [sum (lens [:i]):sum (lens [:i + 1] ) ] for i in range (rails) ]
    maxLen = len (paths [0] )
    paths = [list (path) + ( [] if len (path) == maxLen else [''] ) for path in paths]
    return ''.join (''.join (x) for x in zip (*paths) )
```

---

Explanation of the decryption:

```
length = len (cypher)
```

Store the length of the cypher text in a local variable for convenience.

```
lens = [length // rails + (1 if length % rails > i else 0) for i in range (rails) ]
```

Now we calculate the length of each rail. The length of each rail is the length of the cypher text divided by the number of rails (in your case 3), and maybe (the `if` part) plus `1` if the length is not exactly divisible.

```
paths = [cypher [sum (lens [:i] ):sum (lens [:i + 1] ) ] for i in range (rails) ]
```

Now slice the cypher text into the different rails, according to the rail lengths we have just calculated.

```
maxLen = len (paths [0] )
```

The maximum length of a rail is equal to the length of the first rail.

```
paths = [list (path) + ( [] if len (path) == maxLen else [''] ) for path in paths]
```

Now add an empty character to the end of each rail which is too short, so all rails have the same length and can be zipped.

```
return ''.join (''.join (x) for x in zip (*paths) )
```

Zip the rails, join each resulting tuple into a string, then join all those strings into one long string and return it.

Comment: i cant use the zip_longest thing

Comment: Then either pad the paths, or join them as shown in your original code. The part you were missing is the lengths of the paths. Just grab this line from my code, and work with it in yours.

Comment: you are referring to the lens= line correct?

Comment: See my edit. Now without zip_longest. Only with built-in methods.

Comment: you guys on here make me feel so stupid haha

Comment: hey this works with my decrypt but i honestly dont understand how its working, if you could explain it at all that would be awesome, otherwise thanks

Comment: Gimme a minute and I'll explain.

Comment: Alright, im trying to work it out myself as well.

Comment: thank you hyperboreus, im going to try to rewrite it in a way i understand now, by unzip you just mean let the loop run right?

Comment: For understanding you can do the following: Take my `dec` function, only leave the first two lines and add a third line with `print (lens)`. Then call it with strings of different lengths and see the output. With your code and this information you should be able to decrypt your cyphertexts.

Comment: also im confused what the sum function is doing in paths =

Comment: Well, it sums... The starting index of each slice is the sum of the lengths of its predecessors. The stopping index of each slice is the sum of its own length and the length of its predecessors.

Comment: i am making progress i think, i added what ive got so far to bottom of my post because i cant figure out how to code in comments

Comment: idk how my teacher expects me to figure this out on my own :/

Comment: is there a way i can use my rail 1 rail 2 rail 3 system? that is the only way it makes sense in my head, i get the right rail lengths now but i dont know what to do with them

Comment: Use sydon's solution. It is a lot neater than mine.

Comment: Your `rails` are my `paths`. `rail1 = paths[0]`, `rail2 = paths[1]` and `rail3 = paths [2]`.